How to set &l:formatexpr?
I cannot set &l:formatexpr.
In my .vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim I have the following:
b:format_cmd = $"ruff format --line-length {&l:textwidth} --stdin-filename {shellescape(expand('%'))} --quiet"
&l:formatexpr = $"myfunctions.Prettify({b:format_cmd})"

When I gq in a python file no error is shown but it seems that the builtin gq mechanism is called instead of ruff.
This is how Prettify() function looks like:
export def Prettify(format_cmd: string = ""): number
  # Set format command
  var cmd = $"prettier --prose-wrap always --print-width {&l:textwidth} --stdin-filepath {shellescape(expand('%'))}"
  if !empty(format_cmd)
    cmd = format_cmd
  endif
  echo cmd

  # Set lines interval to filter
  var a = v:lnum
  var b = v:lnum + v:count - 1
  var win_view = winsaveview()
  silent exe $":{a},{b}!{cmd}"
  # Undo if the formatter progs detects errors or if it is not installed
  if v:shell_error != 0
    silent! undo
    echoerr "The program used for formatting is either not installed or it returned errors"
  endif
  winrestview(win_view)
  return 0
enddef


First, the basics: what does :verbose set formatexpr say when in a python file? Second, why don't you simply use &formatprg in your function? That would save you a few seemingly unnecessary steps and make &formatexpr simpler and more generic.


&formatexpr option is correctly set. 2. &formatprg make difficult to deal with visual selections 3. The issue was that formatexpr shall be a function with no arguments.


Not sure why "&formatprg make difficult to deal with visual selections" but OK. Consider writing an answer and accepting it if you solved your problem.

In general, "&formatprg" prog would be called for each line in the visual selection, making it inefficient. Unless you save the selected lines in a temp file or by making convoluted hops. I prefer to call the external program once, passing the line interval that I need to format and &formatexpr seems to be better suited for the task.

No. &formatprg is only called once, like a filter. It would be useless otherwise because formatting is about context and it wouldn't have any.

FWIW, here is the generic function I use for all my &formatexpr needs:
function! foo#bar#FormatExpr()
    let l1 = v:lnum
    let l2 = (v:lnum + v:count) - 1
    let tempfile = tempname()

    call getline(l1, l2)->writefile(tempfile)

    let output = systemlist(expandcmd(&formatprg) .. ' < ' .. tempfile)

    if v:shell_error
        echohl WarningMsg | echo 'Shell error: ' .. v:shell_error | echohl None
        return v:shell_error
    else
        execute 'silent ' .. l1 .. ',' .. l2 .. 'd_'

        if wordcount().bytes == 0
            call setline('.', output)
        else
            execute 'silent ' .. (l1 - 1) .. 'put=output'
        endif

        return 0
    endif
endfunction

as well as a wrapper that handles cursor position, for use in autocommands:
function! foo#bar#FormatAndComeBack()
    let gqview = winsaveview()

    silent normal! gggqG

    call winrestview(gqview)
endfunction

and a custom "format without moving" operator for good measure, because I generally favor <operator><motion> over v<motion><operator>:
function! GQ(type, ...)
    normal! '[v']gq

    call winrestview(w:gqview)

    unlet w:gqview
endfunction
nmap <silent> gq :let w:gqview = winsaveview()<CR>:set opfunc=GQ<CR>g@

Rationale…

I use a temporary file to perform the formatting out-of-band because it is cleaner than doing it in-band: no need to undo, no visual jankiness.

I use the existing &formatprg because it already exists for that exact purpose, it is canonical, and I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

With the setup above, after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim looks something like:
setlocal formatprg=whatever
setlocal formatexpr=foo#bar#FormatExpr()
augroup <filetype>
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> silent call foo#bar#FormatAndComeBack()
augroup END

which seems quite clean and straightforward to me.
Some filetypes require a bit of logic to define &formatprg, though, but that's hardly an issue.

I keep the filetype-specific stuff in the relavant filetype plugins in order for the generic stuff to stay generic. foo#bar#FormatExpr(), foo#bar#FormatAndComeBack(), and GQ() have literally no idea of what happens under the hood, which is how these thing should work.



Nice, but It seems that on Windows temp files are not automatically cancelled at Vim exit.

Indeed but I don't use Windows. If you need Windows support, then do delete(tempfile) after you have used it. The exact syntax of the command in systemlist() might be different as well. YMMV.

This is not very specific to 'formatexpr', but it implements a simplified version of a generic formatter by using 'formatprg' instead.
# --------- General formatting function -----------------
export def FormatWithoutMoving(a: number = 0, b: number = 0)
  var view = winsaveview()
  if a == 0 && b == 0
    silent exe $":norm! gggqG"
  else
    var interval = b - a + 1
    silent exe $":norm! {a}gg{interval}gqq"
  endif

  if v:shell_error != 0
    undo
    echoerr $"'{&l:formatprg->matchstr('^\s*\S*')}' returned errors."
  endif
  winrestview(view)
enddef

# Creating dedicated files for these other filetypes with all the same content may be not optimal
var prettier_supported_filetypes = ['json', 'yaml', 'html', 'css']
def SetFormatter()
  if !empty(&filetype)
      && index(prettier_supported_filetypes, &filetype) != -1
      && executable('prettier')
    var cmd = $"prettier --prose-wrap always --print-width {&l:textwidth}
          \ --stdin-filepath {shellescape(expand('%'))}"
    &l:formatprg = cmd
  endif
enddef

augroup PRETTIFY
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * SetFormatter()
augroup END

In python.vim I have (among other stuff):
&l:formatprg = $"ruff format --line-length {&l:textwidth}
      \ --stdin-filename {shellescape(expand("%"))} --quiet"

# Autocmd to format with ruff
augroup PYTHON_FORMAT_ON_SAVE
    autocmd! * <buffer>
    autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> myfunctions.FormatWithoutMoving()
augroup END


The problem relied in that formatexpr shall be a function with no arguments.
EDIT: although the above line answers the specific question on how to set 'formatexpr', below it is reported an example on how to use it for a general formatter. However, other replies may implement more efficient solutions.
I found the following solution, which is rather general.
The formatter is set according to a b:format_cmd variable. Such a  variable is set in <filetype>.vim file (in my case in python.vim and it uses ruff). If such a variable does not exist, then the prettier formatter is used if &filetype is in a list. Otherwise, whatever is set is used.
So, in my case, if &filetype is python it uses ruff, else if &filetype is e.g. markdown use prettier, otherwise use whatever it is currently associated to gq.
In .vim/lib/myfunctions.vim I have the following:
# --------- General formatting function -----------------
export def FormatWithoutMoving(a: number = 0, b: number = 0)
  var view = winsaveview()
  if a == 0 && b == 0
    exe $":norm! gggqG"
  else
    var interval = b - a + 1
    exe $":norm! {a}gg{interval}gqq"
  endif
  winrestview(view)
enddef

# ---- Prettify function ------
def Prettify(format_cmd: string = ""): number
  # Set format command
  var cmd = $"prettier --prose-wrap always --print-width {&l:textwidth} --stdin-filepath {shellescape(expand('%'))}"
  if !empty(format_cmd)
    cmd = format_cmd
  endif

  echom cmd

  # Set lines interval to filter
  var a = v:lnum
  var b = v:lnum + v:count - 1
  exe $":{a},{b}!{cmd}"
  # Undo if the formatter progs detects errors or if it is not installed
  if v:shell_error != 0
    silent! undo
  endif
  return 0
enddef

var prettier_supported_filetypes = ['markdown', 'json', 'yaml', 'html', 'css']
def SetFormatter()
  # 1. If b:format_cmd is found use that one
  # 2. Otherwise use 'prettier' if &filetype is in the list
  # 3. Otherwise use whatever it was set.
  if exists('b:format_cmd')
    b:Prettify_func = () => Prettify(b:format_cmd)
    &l:formatexpr = "b:Prettify_func()"
  elseif !empty(&filetype) && index(prettier_supported_filetypes, &filetype)
      != -1
    &l:formatexpr = "Prettify()"
  endif
enddef

augroup PRETTIFY
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * SetFormatter()
augroup END

in .vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim I have the following:
b:format_cmd = $"ruff format --line-length {&l:textwidth} --stdin-filename {shellescape(expand("%"))} --quiet"

and in my .vimrc I have the following:
import ".vim/lib/myfunctions.vim"

nnoremap Q <ScriptCmd>myfunctions.FormatWithoutMoving()<cr>
xnoremap Q <esc><ScriptCmd>myfunctions.FormatWithoutMoving(line("'<"), line("'>"))<cr>

